# Set the width of facebook login button to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I need to set the width of the facebook login button to 100%. According to the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/ it should be as simple as adding `data-width` attribute:

```
<div
  class="fb-login-button"
  data-width="100%"
  data-max-rows="1"
  data-size="large"
  data-button-type="continue_with"
  data-use-continue-as="true"
></div>
```

But it doesn't work (the button simply doesn't show up). Even when I enter the width of 100% on their official form for generating buttons it doesn't work. Is it some kind of a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: data-size large limits the width to 400px max?

Comment: @Pete yes it possible to enter 400px, but i would like it be longer, I'm starting thinking that it's impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the Facebook Button. Build your own button and use the Javascript SDK from Facebook

`FB.login()` of JavaScript-SDKs.

[facebook-login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/)  ---> point 3

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v3.2

Comment: Most likely it's the only solution, I though that there should be a way to do it with the official button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>

    <div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-width="100%" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">Button</div>
```

If it doesn't work add the below css :

```
     .fb-login-button {
        width: 100%;
     }
```

Comment: Make sure that the parent div is full width also :)

Comment: Anyway the button takes up 100% but no more than 400px. I want it to be longer than 400px.

Comment: set data-size to 1000px ?

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs, it seems that you can't edit data-width, I think it is only used when you are migrating from an old version.

The only property that seem to be what you're looking for is "data-size", and can take 3 params : "small, medium, large"

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use css to style the button?

```css
.fb-login-button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); //only for debug
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-hype="continue_with" data-use-continue-as="true">
    FACEBOOK
</div>
```

Comment: Then it takes up 400px, but I need 100%.

Comment: That would be styling the original element that triggered rendering of the button only. The button itself loads in an iframe, and you have no access to the content inside for styling purposes.

Comment: Ah ok. I did not know that via the Facebook button

Answer (score 0):

First we need to understand that widths in percentages are relative to the parent or containing element. If the parent is not-bound by a static width or a proportion of the full width, we can state width: 100% in the CSS. By adding width: 100% to the style we get the full width, see the following jsfiddle:
[Facebook login button](https://jsfiddle.net/q1k4w3gp/)

```
<div id="spinner"
style="
    background: #4267b2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;">
Facebook Login
<div
class="fb-login-button"
data-max-rows="1"
data-size="large"   
data-button-type="continue_with"
data-use-continue-as="true"
></div>
```